# How to create an xml with multile root nodes

Tags: java

Example-

```
<Envision>
      <Employee>
         <Employee-code>Shiva kumar</Employee-code>
         <Employee-Name>474</Employee-Name>
      </Employee>
  <Employee>
         <Employee-code>Santhosh Kumar</Employee-code>
         <Employee-Name>475</Employee-Name>
      </Employee>
</Envision>
```

I want to create an xml file as shown above xml.But i am able to do only this -

```
<Employee>
<Employee-code>Shiva kumar</Employee-code>
<Employee-name>474</Employee-name>
<Employee>

</Envision>
```

by following code-

DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

```
  DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();

  Document doc=builder.newDocument();

  Element root=doc.createElement("Envision");

  doc.appendChild(root);

  Element ele=doc.createElement("Employee_Name");
  ele.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Shiva Kumar"));
  root.appendChild(ele);

  ele=doc.createElement("Employee_Code");
  ele.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("474"));
  root.appendChild(ele);

  TransformerFactory transformerFactory =TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
  StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(System.out);
  transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Whenever i want to add second block to that code by appending this below code to above code
after the employee code tag

```
  Element root1=doc.createElement("Envision");

  doc.appendChild(root1);


      ele=doc.createElement("Employee_Name");
  ele.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Vijay Babu"));
  root1.appendChild(ele);

  ele=doc.createElement("Employee_Code");
  ele.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(""));
  root1.appendChild(ele);
```

Then i am gettting an Error message like "Creation of the node is not permitted".Please help me in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a second root element - that's simply invalid in XML. But you don't need to. All you need to do is reuse your *existing* root element. Look at the XML at the top of the question - it only has a single root element, with two `Employee` elements, right?

It's not clear why you're not creating `Employee` elements, by the way. You're currently creating `Employee_Name` and `Employee_Code` directly under `Envision`, which doesn't match your sample XML.

I would suggest extracting out the employee-adding code like this:

```
private static void addEmployee(Document doc, String name, String code) {
    Element employee = doc.createElement("Employee");
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(employee);

    Element nameElement = doc.createElement("Employee_Name");
    nameElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(name));
    employee.appendChild(nameElement);

    Element codeElement = doc.createElement("Employee_Code");
    codeElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(name));
    employee.appendChild(codeElement);
}
```

Then:

```
Document doc = builder.newDocument();        
Element root = doc.createElement("Envision");        
doc.appendChild(root);

addEmployee(doc, "Shiva Kumar", "474");
addEmployee(doc, "Vijay Babu", "");
```

(Alternatively, you could change `addEmployee` to take the element to append it to.)

Answer (score 0):

XML file can have only one root element. Therefore if you really need more *Envision* nodes then create one root node for them e.g. *ENVISIONS*

```
<ENVISIONS>
  <ENVISION>
  ...
  <ENVISION>
  <ENVISION>
  ...
  <ENVISION>
</ENVISIONS>
```

Haven't you forgotten to create *EMPLYEE* node, have you?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the root element, you can't create and append another root element to the document.

```
doc.appendChild(root);
```

If you want to get that root element to append another employee element to it later you can call the doc.getDocumentElement()

```
Element root1=doc.getDocumentElement()
```